# Handle different view controllers to achieve different views at orientation change

Tags: view, orientation, storyboard, controllers

I have a universal app that i need to present different screen for ipad depending if the device is portrait or landscape. I am using storyboards and view controllers. In the ipad storyboard I have one view controller for Portrait and one for landscape both pointing to the same .m class and each has an identifier name.

At the didRotate method in each .m file i tried to load the correct view cotroller based on its identifier name and i used push in the navigation controller.  But in this way the back button doesnt lead back to the correct orientation of the previous view.